# How to disable screen dimming in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, display, brightness

When I am inactive for 4-5 minutes, the screen is automatically dimmed. This is too much boring when I am watching movie. How to disable this thing??

Comment: I just want to add that in Google Chrome there's no such problem, so apparently it's not obligatory to install some software to prevent this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install [Caffeine](https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ppa) to do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

Then search for Caffeine in your Dash to start it. It should start automatically after a reboot.

Now Caffeine will show an indicator in the top right of your screen. Click on it to enable Caffeine (your PC won't go to sleep now). Click again to disable it and Ubuntu will follow its usual sleep schema.

---

You can also disable the sleep permanently if you prefer.

1. Open `System Settings`
2. Click on `Brightness & Lock`
3. At `Turn screen off when inactive for` select `Never`

Comment: fails to work on my ideapad...

Comment: I have done your second option using system settings, but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

1. System Tools -> Preferences -> Power
2. Click on "screen brightness" in the Tip message:

> Tip: screen brightness affects how much power is used

3. Select "Never" for "Turn screen off when inactive for:"

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Cleanup any bad state we left behind if the user exited while flash was
# running
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled --type bool true

we_turned_it_off=0

while true; do
    sleep 60
    flash_on=0

    for pid in `pgrep firefox` ; do
        if grep libflashplayer /proc/$pid/maps > /dev/null ; then
            flash_on=1
        fi

        ss_on=`gconftool-2 -g /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled`

        if [ "$flash_on" = "1" ] && [ "$ss_on" = "true" ]; then
            gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled \
                --type bool false
            we_turned_it_off=1
        elif [ "$flash_on" = "0" ] && [ "$ss_on" = "false" ] \
                && [ "$we_turned_it_off" = "1" ]; then
            gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled \
                --type bool true
            we_turned_it_off=0
        fi

    done
done
```

save it as .sh file and add this file to session and startup