# Screen tuns off during skype video conversation

Tags: skype, lock-screen

Fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 in EFI mode. During skype video conversation screen turns off when, it reaches it value set in **"Brightness and Lock"** -> **"Turn off screen when inactive for"** . Is there any way to prevent dimming during video,except set **"Turn off screen when inactive for"** Never? Skype versions 4.2.0.13, 4.2.0.11. 
Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Skype issue, it is a Ubuntu setting. This will happen in **any** application you start when you're inactive (no user input) for `x` minutes.

As said you can set this setting to `Never` to disable it. You can also install an applet so you can easily disable it with just one click. To do this, please take a look at my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/459598/270074).

Comment: Thanks, I saw your answer in another thread earlier. Just was interesting about skype, because VLC, Totem, HTML5 Youtube video works fine without screen turning off or locks.

Comment: Are you sure you're not accidentally touching your mouse or something like that then?

Comment: Double-checked, set "Turn off screen when inactive for" 1 minute, no mouse connected, turned touchpad off, my laptop stands aside. I was pleasantly surprised when i first noticed this behavior out of the box with video and html5 video. When watching adobe flash video, screen still turns off

Comment: You mean it doesn't turn off with video or HTML5 video? That's strange. But still, I think this is the only solution for your problem. Skype development seems to be very bad for Linux.

Comment: Yes. I know, just thought there is another solution. Thanks, anyway