# Laptop screen dimming after (? random) period 14.04

Tags: 14.04, laptop, backlight

We have a Lenovo X220 and an X230 both running Ubuntu 14.04.

Intermittently, and for no obvious reason, after opening the lid and resuming, for which we require passwords, the backlight will dim to a low level. This can be corrected using keys, but may recur.

I have checked such fixes as are mentioned elsewhere on the site but to no avail. My credibility as Tech Support with my wife is threatened.... :-)

All ideas welcome, apart from 'buy a Mac', which is what my wife would like, but which neither of us can afford...

B.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, everything is a file, so `backlight` configurations are saved as a file. You can create a custom settings file for `backlight`.
This command helps to know what video card is used for the backlight/brightness:

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/
```

In my case output is `intel_backlight`, it might differ for you depending on drivers.
create a configuration file, if it does not exist:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Add the following lines to this file:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Save, exit, log out and log in again and those settings should work and laptop screen should not dim. In your case, you need to restart the system

Comment: Thanks - I'd found this answer and tried it - the lines were in the file anyway and made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could for sure disable dimming in general - if that is an option for you.

- System Tools
- Preferences
- Power

Click on **screen brightness** and choose **Never** for **Turn screen off when inactive for**.

More ideas regarding disabling dimming can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459591/how-to-disable-screen-dimming-in-14-04).

Comment: Thanks very much - I was sure I had tried this (as had my wife!), but looking at the settings it seems not. So I shall try and report back!

Comment: So I shall try and report back!

Comment: OK. I hadn't changed this setting but have now. My wife had - her screen dimmed for no reason while we were examining the settings, so this would seem not to be the answer. All ideas welcome!